# How can I convert an enum constant into a key-value pair of it's field values?

Tags: java, enums

I have a Java enum class with multiple enum constants defined with multiple fields per constant.

I want to be able to convert an enum constant into a key-value pair list containing the field name and values.

The difficulty comes from creating a setup that will allow for users to only need to add a new enum constant or even add new fields to each constant and not have the code consuming this data know about which fields will exist.

```
public enum Stuff
{
  ORDINAL_ZERO( "Zero's identifier", "Zero's value A", "Zero's value B" ),
  ORDINAL_ONE( "One's identifier", "One's value A", "One's value B" );

  private String identifer;
  private String valueA;
  private String valueB;

  Stuff( String identifier, String valueA, String valueB )
  {
    this.identifier = identifier;
    this.valueA = valueA;
    this.valueB = valueB;
  }

  public static Stuff getStuffForIdentifier( String identifier )
  {
    for ( Stuff stuff : values() )
    {
      if ( stuff.getIdentifier().equalsIgnoreCase( identifier ) )
        return stuff;
    }
  }

  public static Map<String, String> getStuffForIdentifierAsMap( String identifier )
  {
    TODO: return a key-value pair map of a single enum constant where I can iterate through the keys and get their values without knowing what all fields are defined ahead of time i.e. if we asked for a map of the 0 ordinal constant's fields:
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("identifier", "Zero's identifer");
    map.put("valueA", "Zero's value A");
    map.put("valueB", "Zero's value B");
    return map;
  }
}
```

Comment: I would opt for introspection/reflexion.

Comment: I don't get this part: `a key-value pair map of a single enum constant where I can iterate through the keys and get their values without knowing what all fields are defined ahead of time`

Comment: jhamon, Can't put code here... see edit to main post shortly. How can I better word that?

Holy shit I just want a return line to separate to messages within one comment... ArnaudDenoyelle, I'm sure it will invove reflection, but I can't quite figure it out.

Comment: The description sounds like a map of maps - something like `Map<Stuff, Map<String, String>>`.  So perhpas something like a `StuffProperties` class to hide the data structure and provide an iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on Stuff.values() in order to find the one with the right identifier

```
public static Map<String, Object> getStuffForIdentifierAsMap(String identifier) 
  throws IllegalAccessException {
    for (Stuff stuff : Stuff.values()) {
        if(stuff.getIdentifier().equals(identifier)) {
          ...
        }
```

**Note** : calling `Stuff.values()` each time you call the method is evil because it will create a new copy of the array each time. On production code, you would avoid that with some cache.

Then, you can iterate on the fields of the class like this :

```
private static Map<String, Object> dumpValues(Stuff stuff) throws IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (Field field : stuff.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        map.put(field.getName(), field.get(stuff));
    }
    return map;
}
```

**Test** :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> props = getStuffForIdentifierAsMap("Zero's identifier");

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : props.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

**Output** :

```
ORDINAL_ONE : ORDINAL_ONE
identifier : Zero's identifier
valueB : Zero's value B
valueA : Zero's value A
ORDINAL_ZERO : ORDINAL_ZERO
$VALUES : [Lcom.denodev.Stuff;@60e53b93
```

Note : you get some extra properties from the class itself.

Comment: the field.get(stuff) is what I was missing. I knew how to build a list of existing fields, but didn't know how to reference their values. I also checked if the field is an isEnumConstant() and isSythetic() in order to ignore the additional properties from the class itself.

Thanks!